# Rigify vertex groups mesh deform error

Tags: bones, weight-painting, rigify, vertex-weights

So I imported a model into Blender that already has vertex groups and a skeleton. I then imported a metarig and made it the exact same shape as the imported skeleton. I applied the armature modifier and deleted the custom skeleton and then  I made another armature modifier and set the object to the Metarig. The mesh deforms fine. So then I generated a rigify for the model and it worked out fine. However, I went to the DEF bones layer and I saw that the arm and leg bones were subdivided. So I then set armature deform of empty groups to the bones and I renamed the original vertex groups to the arm and legs vertex groups. I then cut the weight paint in half for the subdivided bones manually like so:[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[image]

But when I pose the arm, the mesh deforms incorrectly at the armpit:

[image]

What should I do to fix the mesh deform problem? Auto weights is not an option because this model has too many accessories like a crowbar and many pouches. Thanks for your time.

Comment: based on second image, it should be fairly easy to manually fix, in weight paint mode...?  There should be (at least) a vertex under that arm, with some high undesired weight.

Comment: m.ardito Thank you for your input. I would post a image of the mesh's correct deform if I could, but I only can post 2 images. My question was ill formed, so what I meant to say was why does rigify mess up the vertex groups when the vertex groups are fine in the Metarig?

Comment: Understanding why, without having your exact model and without being able to replicate all your edits is near to impossible, unfortunately... have you tried with older blender versions, just in case, or even the new 2.78a?

Comment: I'm using Blender 2.78a.

Comment: @Abe could you please share the .blend file so we can help you?

Comment: @take I just manually edited the vertex groups in edit mode and that fixed it. What confuses me is why the mesh doesn't deform correctly by renaming the vertex groups from the Metarig to the rigify rig. I divided the weight corresponding to the subdivided bones and everything, the color/size of the weight paint is the same as in the metarig.

Answer (score 0):

I know what I did wrong! The bad mesh deform is because I didn't rename all of the vertex groups and just the arm groups. The weight paint was overlapping from the chest vertex group and renaming it fixed the bad deform.